# Counting Graphs which are a sum of Cycles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are graphs with vertex set $V(G), V(H)$ and edge set $E(G), E(H)$ respectively.  Define the sum $G+H$ to be the graph with vertex set $V(G) \cup V(H)$ and edge set $E(G) \cup E(H)$

How many unlabelled isomorphism classes of graphs are there on $n$ vertices which are a sum of cycle graphs on more than $3$ vertices?

So for example there are $2$ such graphs on $6$ vertices namely $C_6$ and $C_3 + C_3$. There are $4$ on $9$ vertices: $C_9$, $C_3+C_6$, $C_4 + C_5$ and $C_3 + C_3 + C_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it more simply, you are asking for the number of unlabelled $2$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices; equivalently, the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ into parts $\ge3.$ This is OEIS sequence [A008483](http://oeis.org/A008483).